# J2ME problem in using TWUIK framework

Tags: java-me

i am developing application in which requirement is to use TWUIK framework in J2ME

i have worked with j2me polish as well as LWUIT but i didnt find any kind of help regarding
TWUIK. Even i am not able to create sample application which simply contain two textbox for login.

core style in TWUIK is to creating every component on canvas
i can create textbox but cant even get focus to that component

Experts any one can guide me???

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is TWUIK by the way, benefits over LWUIT?

Comment: actually it is a framework created by tricastmedia it has more features related to graphics and effects. it has combined svg and fx. just only one drawback i found is they are not giving good help and sample application and its not freeware. you have to purchase licence for using it.